# Android, String Array can't go BACKWARDS from [0] TO [6(last String)] (Button = Button -1), CRASH

Tags: java, android, arrays, string

Whenever my back_button reaches the String[0] and I try proceeding going backwards my App just crashes.

Instead of simply going from String[0] to my currently last string [6] and continue  to go backwards (if the conditions are met), why it doesnt do that ?

My code for that Button, btw im new to programming and I know my Code is EXTREMLY TRASH.. but, that's another topic, please xD :

```
  back_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            forward_button.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            backButton();

            if (mediator == 10) {

                forward_button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                backk--;
                display.setText(list[backk]);
            }


            if (backk == currentnumber-5 ) {
                back_button.setClickable(false);
            }
            if (backk != currentnumber-5) {
                back_button.setClickable(true);
                back_button.setEnabled(true);
            }



            if (mediator != 10){
                back_button.setEnabled(false);
                display.setText(list[currentnumber]);

            }
        }



    });
```

Btw. I thought it maybe has something to do with this Code right here in my other's Button Logic, maybe there is a similiar function to call for when going from String [0] to String [last string(6)] ?

```
  if (currentnumber == list.length) {
                currentnumber = 0;
                backk = 0;
                back = 1;
```

EDIT : I deleted if ( backk < 0 ) { ... , I dont know why it was in there to begin with, sorry, that wasnt supposed to be in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your block, make the following change:

```
if (mediator == 10) {

    forward_button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    backk--;

    // If we go below the size of the array, add the array
    // size to loop back to the last element in the array
    if (backk < 0){
        backk += list.length;
    }
    display.setText(list[backk]);
}
```

If you explain what it is you're trying to accomplish and post more of your code, I might be able to help clean up your code a little with comments on why I make the choices I do.  But the change above will fix that array out of bounds crash.

Comment: Hey, it does work , but then , I just want the button to move back 5 Strings no further, but adding that code seems to manipulate the numbers and I get issues basically.
What does the  backk += list.length; do ?
Especially number wise.

Comment: alright, in my if conditions I wrote back -5 instead of currentnumber -5 , and then I also wrote back += list.length; below backk += list.length; 
It does work now as intended, but one ugly thing, I have to tap twice if that function was used to change the displayed string. 
Now how to handle that ? I know you dont really know my Code

Comment: If you can sort of explain in normal language what you're really trying to do with this code, then I can try to help you clean it up.  I just can't tell what the goal is.  Let me know what each variable means and how they interact and what you want the button to do.  

What I did here is check to see if you had backed up one time too many.  If you had, I made your backk index point to the end of the array.  So the array would loop basically.